# Unable to npm install my package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been trying to install a package that I have defined the **package.json** for. The **package.json** file is very simple.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma-jasmine": "0.2.2"
  }
}
```

Now when I issue a

```
npm install .
```

I get the following error.

```
npm WARN package.json package.json@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/username/projects/project
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "."
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.5
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno 28

npm ERR! EISDIR, read
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/projects/project/npm-debug.log
```

Unable to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this I finally figured out the cause. I didn't have a **package.json** file but I had it **misspelt** as packages.json file.

NPM wasn't able to pick up the file from the current directory and then it tried my home directory and then showed the unhelpful error. I hope this will help somebody save some time.

Answer (score 6):

Top Tip - once you have created your new project's github repository and cloned it locally, issue the command :

```
npm init
```

which will prompt you for particulars and auto synthesize a file

```
package.json
```

for you

UPDATE :  I see its been fixed ... my current version has a much better error message :

```
npm install
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/scott/aaa/package.json'


node --version
v5.4.1

npm --version
3.3.12
```

Comment: This is a great tip for that workflow but once your file is gone and you issue npm install the error message is so cryptic that I think the solution mentioning that you are missing the file or have misspelt is more valuable.

Comment: the crew over at npm are very responsive - I strongly suggest U book them an Issue at their   https://github.com/npm/npm    so we all benefit from their/our  fix (hopefully)