# npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, npm

So I just created my new Angular application and whenever I restore my packages by right-clicking package.json file and selecting `Restore Packages` option, I get these npm errors below. How do I resolve them?

I had a look at this link [Npm Error - Windows NT - How to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965938/npm-error-windows-nt-how-to-resolve) but the solutions provided are based on the user's specific OS registry information.

I'm using a 64-bit OS. Running VS 2015 Update 3. I have Node JS installed and running the following commands confirms this:

1. `node -v:` **v6.10.3**
2. `npm -v:` **v3.10.10**

Unrelated third check:

3. TypeScript is installed and is VS is running **2.3.3.0**

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>       npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>       npm ERR! node v6.10.3
>       npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>       npm ERR! path C:\Users\Linda\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules.staging\source-map-support-b3871625
>       npm ERR! code ENOENT
>       npm ERR! errno -4058
>       npm ERR! syscall rename
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Linda\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules.staging\source-map-support-b3871625' -> 'C:\Users\Linda\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\source-map-support'
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules.staging\source-map-support-b3871625' -> 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\source-map-support'
>       npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>       npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       npm ERR! enoent 
>       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\Linda\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\npm-debug.log
>       angular-quickstart@1.0.0 C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test

After going over [Unable to npm install my package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586830/unable-to-npm-install-my-package) here are the following checks I did:

1. I have a package.json file and it is not misspelled.
2. I checked my devDependencies and the version that package.json file is running on seems to be **1.0.0** (run on via the lite server)
3. Here is my devDependencies of my package.json file:

   "devDependencies": {
           "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
           "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
           "typescript": "~2.1.0",

   ```
       "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
       "tslint": "^3.15.1",
       "lodash": "^4.16.4",
       "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
       "karma": "^1.3.0",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
       "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
       "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
       "protractor": "~4.0.14",
       "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

       "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
       "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
     },
     "repository": {}
   ```

The error does state that this is not a problem with npm but it not being able to find a file. What file is this?

**UPDATE:**
I noticed that the **.staging** folder is none existent in my project directory as per the below error.

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\.staging\source-map-support-b3871625' -> 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\source-map-support'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\.staging\source-map-support-b3871625' -> 'C:\Users\User\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\node_modules\source-map-support'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply ran the following command and the error(s) went away.

```
npm install -g grunt
```